# Solspace User - Can registration form have group specified w/email activation?

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

I'm using exp:user:register, the group_id parameter (https://www.solspace.com/docs/user/register/#group_id), but it's being ignored. I see in the documentation that "This parameter respects native EE account activation settings," so does this mean I can't set group_id as long as I have email activation set?

In EE Member Preferences, there's "Default Member Group Assigned to New Members" that is being used instead. But I'd like to override this using exp:user:register. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `Require Member Account Activation?` Setting in `Members > Preferences` jphansen??

If it's self activation, the `group_id` parameter should override your `Default Member Group Assigned to New Members` *once the user activates* via the supplied link in their email.

If its No Activation required, then it should add the user to that user group on registration.

Otherwise (Manaul Admin activation), I'm not sure but I beleive the admin activation process is for the admin to move the user from the 'pending' group to the relivent (selected by admin) group, ergo no need for this field.

SolSpace (the user here) should chip in soon, so will be able to help if it's not going as above...

Comment: Thanks Blatant. The Require Member Account Activation setting is Self-activation via email. The user registers, clicks the link in their email to activate, then they're added to the group in Members > Preferences > Default Member Group Assigned to New Members, not the group I specified in {exp:user:register group_id="x"}. I'm using EE 2.7.3 and User 3.5.2.

Comment: OK just tested it again and it's working now.

Comment: Always good when things correct themselves ;)